# Using `pkexec` for escalation in a snap?

Tags: python, gtk, snapcraft, snap, polkit

I am writing a GTK gui in Python and I have this line

```
subprocess.run("pkexec (some command)", shell=True)
```

which I have attached to a button in my GUI, but when I try to use the button I get this error

```
/bin/sh:1:pkexec:not found
```

The GUI relies on pkexec since it calls a command that normally requires sudo. Is there any way to get this to work?